# Open Type (Ctrl+Shift+T) in Eclipse from every window

Tags: java, eclipse, keymapping, file-search

If I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in **Eclipse**, an **Open Type** window opens. But this works only if I am in a Java file (or in the Package Explorer area).

I want to open the same window when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> regardless of the resource (E.g.: if the open file is .js, .class or .xml).

How can I achieve this?

---

**Details**:

- Operating system: **Windows 7**
- IDE: **Eclipse Luna (4.4)**

I tried to:

- go to *Window > Preferences > General > Keys > type "Open Type" / "Ctrl+Shift+T"*
- let only the following line for `Ctrl+Shift+T` / `Open Type`:

  ```
  Command:   Open Type
  Binding:   Ctrl+Shift+T
  When:      In Windows
  Category:  Navigate
  ```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You should filter by the binding, not the command:

- go to *Window > Preferences > General > Keys*
- Type "Ctrl+Shift+T"
- Press *Unbind Command* for all bindings except the one you described above

After applying the changes, the "Open (Java) Type" dialog should also open when in a JavaScript editor.

Comment: I don't have another binding for Ctrl + Shift + T. The only line is that one that is described above and it works only from Java files (+ Package Explorer area). I updated the post according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

This occurs because there are two different "Open Type" commands that share the same key binding (one of which only applies to Javascript files). This can be changed as follows:

1. Go to Window - Preferences.
2. Open General - Keys.
3. Type "Open Type" in the filter text box at the top.
4. In the default setup there are two "Open Type" entries, each with a binding of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>: Select the one with a description of "Open a type in a Java editor" (with "When:" set to "Javascript View").
5. Move the cursor into the "Binding:" field and either delete it (e.g. with the delete or backspace key) or if preferred assign it with a different (unused) combination such as <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
6. Press the Apply button followed by the OK button.

Answer (score 1):

I have it When -> Editing JavaScript Source and it works fine whatever I use it on xml, properties or sql files. Running on Luna version.

Comment: I also have Eclipse Luna (I updated the post), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me because I was in the Resource perspective.  Switching to the Java perspective fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had to set "Open Type" when in "JavaScript View" and now it works for me. I'm using Spring Tool Suite:
`Version: 3.6.3.SR1 Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1)`

And this bug [was reported](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=346173)